# R: how to let .C call update output variable?

Tags: c, r, variables, output

I am trying to write a C code to use in R, but found that the .C function call won't update output variable. The real C code is complicated, but here is a simple example to show the behavior:

```
void doubleMe(const int *input, int *output) {
    output[0] = input[0] * 2;
}
```

Save above C function into file doubleMe.c. Under Linux, compile it to create doubleMe.so file:

```
R CMD SHLIB doubleMe.c
```

In R, if I do following:

```
dyn.load("doubleMe.so") # load it
input = 2
output = 0
.C("doubleMe", as.integer(input), as.integer(output)) # expect output=4

[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 4
```

The screen output indicates the input is doubled, but the output in R is still 0:

```
output
[1] 0
```

If I do fowllwing

```
output = .C("doubleMe", as.integer(input), as.integer(output))[[2]]
```

the output is 4. This should work for the example.

But my real input and output are matrix, and I have to reshape the output to correct dimension. Is there a way to let .C call update output directly?

Comment: The general consensus these days also is to avoid `.C()` and use `.Call()` as it allows for richer semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `.Call()` interface using `SEXP` data types where `P` stands for pointer, this is automagic:

```
R> Rcpp::cppFunction("void doubleMe(NumericVector x) { x = 2*x; } ")
R> x <- 1        # set to one
R> doubleMe(x)   # call function we just wrote
R> x             # check ...
[1] 2            # and it has doubled as a side-effect
R>
```

I use Rcpp here as it allows me to do this on one line, you could do the same in a few lines of C code if you wanted to.